# What should be passed to 'data-append-to' plugin option to make foundation reveal inject into custom div?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Here is my structure(stripped down to demonstrate the issue):

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form>
         <div class="siteContainer">
            <div class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
               <div class="form-fields">
                  <input type="submit" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the structure rendered on browser:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form>
         <div id="siteContainer">
         </div>
         ...
      </form>
      <div class="reveal-overlay">
         <div class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
            <div class="form-fields">
               <input type="submit" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As reveal appends my form container div outside of the form tag, my submit is not working. I used the  [plugin option](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#js-options) data-append-to and passed the id of the site container div but the modal was rendered at the same place.

```
<div class="reveal-modal" data-reveal data-append-to="siteContainer">
```

How can I make the reveal to append inside of my form tag?

Note: I am constrained from using another form tag outside of 'form-fields' div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran in to the same issue.  You need to preface your attribute in the data-append-to with the #.

`data-append-to="#siteContainer"`